# How to jump to the folder by clicking on the link

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I have a link on my application, if the administrator clicks on that link, he will jump to the folder specific on the system `ex : "C:\mySpace\"`. Is there any simple way to do this in jsf (or using javascript)?

Comment: what do you mean by jump  do you mean open it in the explorer folder ?!?

Comment: yes, open file directory in the explorer folder

Comment: try  this command `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));`

Comment: yeah, it works for me. Thanks for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jump (open in explorer) using this command :

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));`

Hope that helped you.

Comment: How is this related to JSF or html or javascript? It is java.awt code. If this really is the answer to the question above, you should learn/teach/tell the OP the question is wrongly tagged and/or help him/her correct it...